# Multiple dispatches while using ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working on a sample Angular 2 application , and using ngrx/store , ngrx/effects for state management.

Below image depicts one of the screens of my application.

[image]

In order to display books list , categories and authors from the server, below dispatch calls are made to the store.

```
this.store.dispatch(loadCatgories());
this.store.dispatch(loadAuthors());       
this.store.dispatch(loadBooks());
```

And below the are the related effects

```
@Effect() authors$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(AuthorActionTypes.LOAD_AUTHORS)
    .switchMap(() => this.authorService.loadAuthors())
    .map(authors => loadAuthorsSuccess(authors));

@Effect() categories$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(CategoryActionTypes.LOAD_CATEGORIES)
    .switchMap(() => this.service.loadCategories())
    .map(categories => loadCategoriesSuccess(categories));      

 @Effect() books$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(BookActionTypes.LOAD_BOOKS)
    .switchMap(() => this.bookService.loadBooks())
    .map(books => loadBooksSuccess(books));
```

My questions are

1. Is the above approach correct or is there any better way , for some reason  some times books list is displayed for second and then they disappear.
2. If my understanding is correct , the above three dispatches are happening parallel, what if I need them to happen one after another.

Comment: 1. The code you posted looks good so far - maybe there is an issue in your reducer or one of the select-calls. - 2. Why is it important to make those calls one after another? The rest-calls don't seem to depend on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why isn't it a good idea to load those items separately ?

- Multiple HTTP requests will slow your app

  - On poor networks this might take a long time
  - Triggers a change detection every time you receive a response (at least 3 times instead of 1)
- If you want to compose your data, for example with selectors, you might end up with **store inconsistency** and you don't want that to happen

---

## What should you do instead ?

Do only one request (I suppose you're the one designing the backend too).
You might just return something like that :

```
{
  authors: ...,
  categories: ...,
  books: ...
}
```

Then you have two options : Dispatch one success action that you'll handle in your 3 reducers separately, or use a lib like [redux-batched-actions](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions) and do the following : 
batchActions([
  loadAuthorsSuccess(res.authors),
  loadCategoriesSuccess(res.categories),
  loadBooksSuccess(res.books)
])

This way, your store will be consistent as only one dispatch will happen.

If you don't have the possibility to modify the backend, use `forkJoin` to launch the requests at the same time and wait for the 3 requests to end before dispatching (once).

***EDIT :***
**Useful links** :
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhA7zZ23Odw
- http://onehungrymind.com/handle-multiple-angular-2-models-ngrx-computed-observables/
- https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-examples
- http://onehungrymind.com/build-better-angular-2-application-redux-ngrx/

I do love this one http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/

Once you have a better understanding of ngrx/store & ngrx/effects, you can also take a look into this repo : https://github.com/teropa/harmonics-explorer

Comment: can you provide any use full links for ngrx store and effects

Comment: @CleanCrispCode I edited my original post to add some useful links ;)

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile there is ngrx-batch-action-reducer. You can define a "batch action" like "LoadBookList" and can define multiple actions with it.