# How to dispatch multiple actions from an effect in ngrx conditionally

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I am a back-end developer starting with front-end development for a project I am working on. The front-end uses Angular7 and NgRx. I have studied a lot in the last 4 days, but here is something I am stuck with and would appreciate your help.

I learnt that we can dispatch multiple actions from an effect in NgRx by returning an Observable array having multiple actions. I want to dispatch one of the action in the array based on a condition.

My code looks something like this

```
@Effect()
  something$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType),
    switchMap.(action: any) => {
       return service.call(action.payload)
         .pipe(
             switchMap((data: ReturnType) => [ 
                new Action1(),
                new Action2(),
              ]),
        catchError(error handling)
      );
    }),
   );
```

and I want to achieve something like this

```
   @Effect()
  something$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType),
    switchMap.(action: any) => {
       return service.call(action.payload)
         .pipe(
             switchMap((data: ReturnType) => [ 
                 if(condition)
                   new Action1()
                  else
                    new Action1.1() ,
                new Action2(),
              ]),
        catchError(error handling)
      );
    }),
   );
```

I think its my lack of knowledge of RxJs, which is preventing me to implement the condition.

Comment: If you are new to Angular adding ngrx to the mix is a terrible idea. Keep things simple with well designed Angular services.

Comment: This should work: `[condition ? new Action() : new AnotherAction(), new Action2()]`. Be wary though, dispatching multiple actions might not always be the best solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488283/multiple-dispatches-while-using-ngrx-store

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can dispatch multiple actions or specific actions by letting conditional ifs determine what iterable to return

I recommend you read: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

```
  @Effect()
  something$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType),
    switchMap(action: any) => {
       return service.call(action.payload)
         .pipe(
             switchMap((data: ReturnType) => {
                 let actionsToDispatch = [];
                 if(condition) {
                   actionsToDispatch.push(new SomeAction())
                 } else {
                   actionsToDispatch.push(new SomeOtherAction())
                 }
                 return actionsToDispatch
              }),
              catchError(error handling)
      );
    }),
   );
```

Answer (score 3):

To dispatch multiple actions you can pass the action array as shown below:

```
@Effect()
getTodos$ = this.actions$.ofType(todoActions.LOAD_TODOS).pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.todoService
      .getTodos()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(todos => [
          new todoActions.LoadTodosSuccess(todos),
          new todoActions.ShowAnimation()
        ]),
        catchError(error => of(new todoActions.LoadTodosFail(error)))
      );
  })
);
```

To dispatch actions conditionally you can wrap the actions in if/else as shown below:

```
@Effect()
getTodos$ = this.actions$.ofType(todoActions.LOAD_TODOS).pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.todoService
      .getTodos()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(todos => {
         if(true) {
             return new todoActions.LoadTodosSuccess(todos),
         } else {
            return new todoActions.ShowAnimation()
         }),
        catchError(error => of(new todoActions.LoadTodosFail(error)))
      );
  })
);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you are just returning an action / multiple actions, you do not need a switchMap you only need map (single) / mergeMap (multiple)

```
@Effect()
getTodos$ = this.actions$.ofType(todoActions.LOAD_TODOS).pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    return this.todoService
      .getTodos()
      .pipe(
        map(todos => {
         if(true) {
             return new todoActions.LoadTodosSuccess(todos),
         } else {
            return new todoActions.ShowAnimation()
         }),
        catchError(error => of(new todoActions.LoadTodosFail(error)))
      );
  })
);

// multiple actions - replace the map with this
mergeMap(todos => [...<array of actions>]
```